# UK Bridges point dataset

Tags: data-request, uk

I am looking for a free dataset of bridges that cover roads/rivers/rail in the UK, specifically South East, as a point layer. It doesn't seem to be available from OS or National Highways, does this exist?
Thanks

Comment: Not a spatial dataset but here is a [list of historic/significant bridges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_bridges_in_the_United_Kingdom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider openstreetmap data. Please have a look on `bridge` tag. You can start with Overpass query like https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1vOs or download the OSM data set for GB: https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/great-britain.html